# How to create stencils of own in Visio 2010?

Tags: visio

I am new to Visio and want to learn more about it. Currently, I am more intrested to learn on how can we create a stencil of our own. Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 4):

That's good that you want to learn [Visio](http://www.visiotoolbox.com). To create a new stencil in Visio you can follow the steps below:
   1) In the Shapes window, click More Shapes, and then select New Stencil.

2) In the Shapes window, right-click the new stencil and select Save As.

3) Type a name for your stencil, and then click Save.

4) By default, custom stencils are saved in your My Shapes folder.

If you want to create a stencil based on an existing one you can follow the steps below:

1) Open the stencil that you want to make a copy of.

2) Right-click the stencil and select Save As.

3) Type a name for your new custom stencil, and then click Save. The new custom stencil appears in the Shapes window.

4) Make any changes that you want to the stencil.

5) To save your changes, right-click the stencil title bar, and then click Save.

However, just for your information you can find some [Visio stencils](http://www.visiotoolbox.com/academicshapes) on their official website www.visiotoolbox.com.